# Fullpage.js not scaling properly on iOS in landscape mode

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, fullpage.js

I am using http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage to create a simple one page website. Everything is perfect except on iPhone when in landscape mode - when I scroll, instead of the page staying full screen and moving to the next anchor, safari reveals address bar & bottom nav causing content to scale in height.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Does this only happen after you've modified anything? Perhaps it's simply a bug that should be reported to the devs?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that the bars are revealed, but that they hide when orientation changes. This is a iOS 7 behavior which may not be the same in other phone OS.

At this moment [developers don't have control over this behavior of Safari over iOS 7](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review).

The bug has been already reported in the github respotitory of fullpage.js but I'm afraid no solution has been found for it yet:
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/79